# Is @AuraEnabled(scope=global) real yet?

Tags: apex, lightning-components, summer-22

I'm trying to test out the new scope attribute for the @AuraEnabled annotation that is supposed to be part of Summer '22, but the compiler doesn't seem to recognize it.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true scope=global)
public static void myMethod(){
```

Anyone had success with it?
Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_EnhancementToAuraEnabledAnnotation.htm&type=5&release=238

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `scope='global'`, you have to enclose the word global within apostrophes. Also you need to use the version 55 to make it work.

Comment: Cool thanks! The doc link on this is missing apostrophes then  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_AuraEnabled.htm.  I wish the page had a place for suggesting edits